# Is there an alphabetic wchar_t such that its capital and lower versions are the same?

Tags: c, trie, wchar-t

I've been wondering whether there is a char `c` such that `iwalpha(c) == 1` and `towlower(c) == towupper(c)`. I'm trying to implement a dictionary in a trie. Each node has a `wchar_t` label and a boolean `a_word` which provides us with the information whether the node represents a word.

I'd like to save such a trie into a file without wasting memory, so I thought I won't save that boolean, but I will write the labels that represent a word with capital case. So my question is whether I'll lose any information that way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `iswalpha` is locale-specific. Anyway, if your locale supports Arabic letters, they should met your conditions.

EDIT: to make an example with extended Latin characters, `towupper('ß') == towlower('ß') == 'ß'`, as long as the locale supprts the Eszett

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that wasn't true though ;)